# When I loop cut a cube and fill a face in the middle, I can't loop cut the cube, I don't know why

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]

When I loop cut a cube and fill a face in the middle,  I can't loop cut the cube, I don't know why

Comment: Each side of a face in blender must have a direction - this means each face must have an "inside" and an "outside" - for a simple cube, this is obvious - all the faces you can see from the outside are facing outwards. However, when you add a (2 sided) face in the middle of the cube, blender now sees one fully enclosed "half cube" (created by the addition of the additional face) with an open-top box attached to it. The geometry is essentially "disconnected" - this is why you cannot add a loop cut.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry/